# AKNode connections after the initializer not working with AKCompressor

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, audiokit

Having troubles with AKNode connections. This is working:

```
compressor = AKCompressor(akMidiSampler)
compressor >>> mixer
```

For some reason, the following connections should work, but no sound

```
compressor = AKCompressor()
akMidiSampler >>> compressor
compressor >>> mixer
```

Just to try, this does not work either, no sound:

```
compressor = AKCompressor(akMidiSampler)
akMidiSampler.disconnectOutput()
akMidiSampler.connect(to: compressor)
compressor >>> mixer
```

Need to make connection after the initializer. Any ideas why it's not working ?

EDIT:

After some testings, I realized that connecting after init this way works with other effects, AKDelay, AKReverb, etc...

But not for AKCompressor. Is it a bug ? Any idea ?

Comment: That is strange. Definitely seems like it could be a bug on our side.

Comment: Can you quickly let us know if it works for any of these? AKDynamicsProcessor, AKExpander, or AKPeakLimiter.  I'm guessing it won't.

Comment: AKExpander and AKPeakLimiter are working good. AKDynamicsProcessor not

Comment: That is weird because AKCompressor and AKExpander are just convenient names that wrap AKDynamicsProcessor.

Comment: Hold up I see a difference.

Comment: I'll update AKCompressor to match AKExpander (and look at AKDynamicsProcessor) - are you able to test changes on the develop branch?

Comment: I never did, but I'll try

Comment: Let me know when it's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed on the develop branch (let me know if not):

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/3d309d6f6a44316fc1eaa386494e3c7cd3a65176

Comment: AKCompressor has a bug on line 148... return inputGain.avAudioNode   change to ... return inputMixer.avAudioNode

Comment: Sorry, yeah, fixed that bug and then also merged in Dave's pull request, so hopefully its better now.